# Finding Minimum Weight Subgraph with k Vertices

Tags: graphs

Assume a complete graph G={V,E} that has n vertices and $C_{n}^{2}$ edges, and the weights of E are all positive. I am trying to find a complete subgraph containing k vertices, and it has the maximum sum of edge weights among all the complete subgraph with k vertices. My question is, other than the brutal force method that needs to traverse all posible subgraph with k vertices ($C_{n}^{k}$), is there an algorithm that is faster than the brutal force, or has polynomial complexity?

Comment: Your problem is NP-complete, even for 1,2 weights, by reduction from CLIQUE.